# How to get magento product id while creating id with REST API

Tags: rest, magento, magento-1.9

How can I get product id while creaing it with REST API at some point in the code product id is passed to this method:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest_Admin_V1
...
    $this->_multicall($product->getId()); #line 172
...
```

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

Ok I did it. I have override `Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest_Admin_V1`
with mine and in `_create()` before `$this->_multicall($product->getId());` I have added:

```
# Return magento product id in response
$this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode(array(
    'magento_product_id' => $product->getId()
)));
```